# What is the "antonym of determinant" that does $f\left(\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}\right)=ad+cb$ called?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm looking for the name of the function
$f\left(\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}\right)=ad+cb$

which I had encountered a long ago on the internet. It is the same as determinant, except that (in Laplace Expansion) even numbered rows/columns don't have the negative sign. I looked at many webpages about matrix operations, but this one wasn't in any of the lists. Maybe it's because it's used rarely?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is called the **permanent** of the matrix $A$, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)). We have
$$
{\rm perm}(A)=ad+bc.
$$